# prove 3 separate subsets of 90 numbers with similar sums

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

"Given a set of 90 numbers , each with 3 digits , prove that there exist 3 subsets which are each separate , that have the same sum (sum of the numbers)."
I know that I should use the pigeonhole principle and somehow divide the subsets into different parts, and a hint says that I should consider 2-membered subsets, but I am unable to correctly divide these subsets to use the pigeonhole principle.
Thanks!

Comment: Is every number of that 90 set different from any other?

Comment: See [Proving subset sums with the pigeon hole principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2227188/318073).

Answer (score 1):

There are $\dbinom{90}{2}=4005$ possible $2$-element subsets of $90$ element set. Alternatively,

Notice we can make $\{a_1,a_2\},\dots,\{a_1,a_{90}\}$ then  $\{a_2,a_3\},\dots,\{a_2,a_{90}\}$ then $\dots$

Which is $(90-1)+(90-2)+\dots+(90-90)=\dfrac12 (90-1) 90=4005$ as claimed.

---

Because all numbers in the set have $3$ digits, we see that:

The smallest and largest possible sums are $100+101=201$ and $999+998=1997$.

This means every sum of those $2$-subsets is in $[201,1997]$ which is $1797$ possibilities.

---

We see now by pigeonhole that there exist $\left\lceil\dfrac{4005}{1797}\right\rceil=3$ many $2$-subsets with same sum.